# Find document with array that consists exclusively particular documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection `path_test` with 2 documents in it

**Document 1**

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "tpc" : 5,
  "path" : [ 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 10, 11 ],
      "ctc" : 2
    }, 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 10 ],
      "ctc" : 2
    }, 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 10, 21 ],
      "ctc" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Document 2**

```
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "tpc" : 5,
  "path" : [ 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 10, 110 ],
      "ctc" : 1
    }, 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 10, 11 ],
       "ctc" : 2
    }, 
    {
      "nids" : [ 0, 5 ],
      "ctc" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to get as a result are documents with `path` array in which all elements have `nids` like `[0, 10, *]`. Order is important, so `[10, 0, *]` will be wrong.
It should find Document 1, but not Document 2. Was hoping I can resolve this with a query, before I start using map-reduce or aggregation.

This is what I've tried so far

**Query1**

```
db.getCollection('path_test').find( {
  "path": { $not: { $elemMatch: { "nids.0": { $nin: [0] }, "nids.1": { $nin: [10] } } } }
});
```

**Query 2**

```
db.getCollection('path_test').find( {
  "path.nids": { $not: { $elemMatch: { $nin: [0, 10] } } }
});
```

but both queries give me results where only 0 is in or where only 10 is in, but I need both and in that exact order.

Is that possible?

Comment: Hope you are aware of this. `$elemMatch` will return only one record that matches the query.

Comment: @Shrabanee Thanks for pointing that out. But I understood it will match at least one element that contains that field.

Comment: @Shrabanee https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: @Shrabanee Your suggestion is wrong. According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/),  the `$elemMatch` operator matches **documents** that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria. It will not return only one record in general case, it will return record, if at least one element in its array field matches all the specified query criteria.

Comment: Do you want to return only those documents where the arrays are sorted? It is hard to understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2):

> not at least one means noone

**Query 1**

For simplification, lets assign

```
A = "nids.0": { $ne: 0 }
B = "nids.1": { $ne: 10 }
C = { A, B }
```

then

```
{ "path" : { $elemMatch: C } }
```

will find documents where at least one element in `path` array satisfies condition `C`, while

```
{ "path" : { $not: { $elemMatch: C } } }
```

will find documents where there are no element in `path` array that satisfies condition `C`.

Document 1 and Document 2 don't have elements in their `path` arrays that satisfy condition `C`, thus the Query1 output contains both of them. If, f.e, you add to the `path` array of the Document 1

```
{ "nids": [ 1, 11, 110], "ctc" : 1 }
```

then Document 1 will not be in the output of Query 1 becase this added element satisfies `C`.

**Query 2**

For simplification, lets assign

```
C = { $nin: [0, 10] }
```

then

```
{ "path.nids" : { $not: { $elemMatch: C } } }
```

will find documents where there are no element in `path.nids` array that satisfies condition `C`.

Document 1 and Document 2 in their `path.nids` arrays have elements that satisfy condition `C`, thus the Query 2 output contains neither of them. If, f.e, you add to you collection document

```
{ "_id" : 6, "tpc" : 5, "path" : [ { "nids" : [ 0, 10 ], "ctc" : 1 } ] }
```

then it will be in the output of Query 2 because in `path.nids` array there are no elements that satisfy `C`.

**Solution**

In Query 1 replace

```
{ $elemMatch: { "nids.0": { $nin: [0] }, "nids.1": { $nin: [10] } } }
```

with

```
{ $elemMatch: { $or: [ { "nids.0": { $ne: 0 } }, { "nids.1": { $ne: 10 } } ] } }
```

This new Query will find documents where there are no element in `path` array that satisfies at least one of conditions `A` and `B`. So, it will find Document 1, but not Document 2 (where `"nids" : [ 0, 5 ]` does not satisfy condition `B`.

Note that `{ $ne: 10 }` is equivalent to `{ $nin: [10] }`.